# Select multiple rows dynamically for Ext.selection.CheckboxModel grid extjs

Tags: extjs, grid

I am unable to select multiple rows dynamically for grid having Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.

I have indexes for the rows which I want to select. What is happening is after select call.

```
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
Ext.getCmp('loadFrameStateInfoTable').getSelectionModel().select(oldStateSelection[i].index);
}
```

I got the selection in grid but for only one row. That's the row which index is coming last from `oldStateSelection[i].index`.

The grid should have all rows selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-select), you need to set *keepExisting* if you don't want the other lines deselected.

```
select(oldStateSelection[i].index, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the doc but I got confused with "keep Existing selections". I thought existing mean the state when grid has been created but its other way i.e. state when you try to select row and keeping state of modified selection. Thanks anyway, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new method for ExtJS 6.2.0 and higher:

`.getSelectionModel().select(i,true)` - worked for me. Here I record the index.

Method documentation:

> `select ( records, [keepExisting], [suppressEvent] )`
> Selects a record instance by record instance or index.
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> - records :  `Ext.data.Model[]/Number` An array of records or an index
> - keepExisting :  `Boolean (optional)` True to retain existing selections; Defaults to: false
> - suppressEvent :  `Boolean (optional)` True to not fire a select event; Defaults to: false